# Spark Streaming check pointing throws Not Serializable exception

Tags: scala, spark-streaming

We are using Spark Streaming Receiver based approach, and we just enabled the Check pointing to get rid of data loss issue.

Spark version is `1.6.1` and we are receiving message from Kafka topic.

I'm using `ssc` inside, `foreachRDD` method of `DStream`, so it throws Not Serializable exception.

I tried extending the class Serializable, but still the same error. It is happening only when we enable checkpoint.

## Code is:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val checkPointLocation = "/path/to/wal"
    val ssc = StreamingContext.getOrCreate(checkPointLocation, () => createContext(checkPointLocation))
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
  }

    def createContext (checkPointLocation: String): StreamingContext ={

        val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Test")
        sparkConf.set("spark.streaming.receiver.writeAheadLog.enable", "true")
        val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(40))
        ssc.checkpoint(checkPointLocation)
        val sc = ssc.sparkContext
        val sqlContext: SQLContext = new HiveContext(sc)
        val kafkaParams = Map("group.id" -> groupId,
        CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG -> sasl,
        ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG -> "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer",
        ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG -> "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer",
        "metadata.broker.list" -> brokerList,
        "zookeeper.connect" -> zookeeperURL)
      val dStream = KafkaUtils.createStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, topicMap, StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER).map(_._2)
      dStream.foreachRDD(rdd =>
        {
           // using sparkContext / sqlContext to do any operation throws error.
           // convert RDD[String] to RDD[Row]
           //Create Schema for the RDD.
           sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
        })
        ssc
    }
```

**Error log:**

> 2017-02-08 22:53:53,250 ERROR [Driver] streaming.StreamingContext:
>   Error starting the context, marking it as stopped
>   java.io.NotSerializableException: DStream checkpointing has been
>   enabled but the DStreams with their functions are not serializable
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext Serialization stack:
>           - object not serializable (class: org.apache.spark.SparkContext, value:
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext@1c5e3677)
>           - field (class: com.x.payments.RemedyDriver$$anonfun$main$1, name: sc$1, type: class org.apache.spark.SparkContext)
>           - object (class com.x.payments.RemedyDriver$$anonfun$main$1, )
>           - field (class: org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3,
>   name: cleanedF$1, type: interface scala.Function1)
>           - object (class org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3,
>   )
>           - writeObject data (class: org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream)
>           - object (class org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream,
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream@68866c5)
>           - element of array (index: 0)
>           - array (class [Ljava.lang.Object;, size 16)
>           - field (class: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer, name: array, type: class [Ljava.lang.Object;)
>           - object (class scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer, ArrayBuffer(org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream@68866c5))
>           - writeObject data (class: org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStreamCheckpointData)
>           - object (class org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStreamCheckpointData, [ 0
>   checkpoint files
>
> ])
>           - writeObject data (class: org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream)
>           - object (class org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaInputDStream,
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaInputDStream@acd8e32)
>           - element of array (index: 0)
>           - array (class [Ljava.lang.Object;, size 16)
>           - field (class: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer, name: array, type: class [Ljava.lang.Object;)
>           - object (class scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer, ArrayBuffer(org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaInputDStream@acd8e32))
>           - writeObject data (class: org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph)
>           - object (class org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph, org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph@6935641e)
>           - field (class: org.apache.spark.streaming.Checkpoint, name: graph, type: class org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph)
>           - object (class org.apache.spark.streaming.Checkpoint, org.apache.spark.streaming.Checkpoint@484bf033)
>           at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.validate(StreamingContext.scala:557)
>           at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.liftedTree1$1(StreamingContext.scala:601)
>           at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.start(StreamingContext.scala:600)
>           at com.x.payments.RemedyDriver$.main(RemedyDriver.scala:104)
>           at com.x.payments.RemedyDriver.main(RemedyDriver.scala)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:559)
>   2017-02-08 22:53:53,250 ERROR [Driver] payments.RemedyDriver$: DStream
>   checkpointing has been enabled but the DStreams with their functions
>   are not serializable org.apache.spark.SparkContext Serialization
>   stack:
>           - object not serializable (class: org.apache.spark.SparkContext, value:
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext@1c5e3677)
>           - field (class: com.x.payments.RemedyDriver$$anonfun$main$1, name: sc$1, type: class org.apache.spark.SparkContext)
>           - object (class com.x.payments.RemedyDriver$$anonfun$main$1, )
>           - field (class: org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3,
>   name: cleanedF$1, type: interface scala.Function1)
>           - object (class org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3,
>   )
>           - writeObject data (class: org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream)
>           - object (class org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream,
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream@68866c5)
>           - element of array (index: 0)
>           - array (class [Ljava.lang.Object;, size 16)
>           - field (class: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer, name: array, type: class [Ljava.lang.Object;)
>           - object (class scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer, ArrayBuffer(org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream@68866c5))
>           - writeObject data (class: org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStreamCheckpointData)
>           - object (class org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStreamCheckpointData, [ 0
>   checkpoint files
>
> ])
>           - writeObject data (class: org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream)
>           - object (class org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaInputDStream,
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaInputDStream@acd8e32)
>           - element of array (index: 0)
>           - array (class [Ljava.lang.Object;, size 16)
>           - field (class: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer, name: array, type: class [Ljava.lang.Object;)
>           - object (class scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer, ArrayBuffer(org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaInputDStream@acd8e32))
>           - writeObject data (class: org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph)
>           - object (class org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph, org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph@6935641e)
>           - field (class: org.apache.spark.streaming.Checkpoint, name: graph, type: class org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph)
>           - object (class org.apache.spark.streaming.Checkpoint, org.apache.spark.streaming.Checkpoint@484bf033) 2017-02-08
>   22:53:53,255 INFO  [Driver] yarn.ApplicationMaster: Final app status:
>   SUCCEEDED, exitCode: 0

**Update:**

Basically what we are trying to do is, converting the rdd to DF[inside foreachRDD method of DStream], then apply DF API on top of that and finally store the data in Cassandra. So we used sqlContext to convert rdd to DF, that time it throws error.

Comment: can you show what is being done inside the foreachRDD? atleast a sample

Comment: @Yuval Itzchakov: Could you please help me on this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to access the `SparkContext`, do so via the `rdd` value:

```
dStream.foreachRDD(rdd => {
  val sqlContext = new HiveContext(rdd.context)
  val dataFrameSchema = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
}
```

This:

```
dStream.foreachRDD(rdd => {
  // using sparkContext / sqlContext to do any operation throws error.
   val numRDD = sc.parallelize(1 to 10, 2)
   log.info("NUM RDD COUNT:"+numRDD.count())
}
```

Is causing the `SparkContext` to be serialized in the closure, which it can't because it isn't serializable.

Comment: @Shankar If you want to work with DataFrames, why not use the Structured Streaming API?

Comment: Does it mean we cannot use createStream or createDirectStream? this is only happening when enabling check pointing.. also Structured Streaming works with SPark 1.6.1?

Comment: @Shankar You can't use `SparkContext` inside `foreachRDD`, that won't work. Structured Streaming with Kafka support starts with Spark 2.0.2 if I recall correctly.

Comment: Since foreachRDD running on Driver, i can use sqlContext normally, but when check pointing, its not working.. is there any other way, i can iterate the rdd from DStream?

Comment: @Shankar Instead of capturing `SparkContext`, try calling `rdd.context` instead and see if that works.

Comment: Itachakov: Sure will try that, i dont have a environment right now, i will try tomorrow first thing and update you....

Comment: @Yuval Do you know why is this behavior occuring only when checkpointing is enabled?